# How do I extracting elements from a complicated, nested .json file in R?

Tags: r, json

My ultimate goal is to read into R a series of daily .xlsx files (named "Community_Profile_Report_YYYYMMDD_Public.xlsx") from the U.S. HealthData website:
[https://healthdata.gov/Health/COVID-19-Community-Profile-Report/gqxm-d9w9[1]](https://healthdata.gov/Health/COVID-19-Community-Profile-Report/gqxm-d9w9%5B1%5D).

To do that, I first have to extract some elements from a .json file and create the URLs, through which I'll iterate to read in the files. How do I extract these elements?

The elements I need are the `assetID` and a `filename` associated with each .xlsx file; both are contained in a .json file in the key/column "metadata_published".  The idea would be to extract the `assetID`s and `filename`s from the .json file, create a list object that contains the `assetID`s and `filename`s, then use an apply method to iterate through URLs I would create using the `assetID`s and `filename`s.

This R code reads in the .json file with the metadata file updates:

```
require(RJSONIO)
df_raw <- RJSONIO::fromJSON("https://healthdata.gov/resource/6hii-ae4f.json", flatten=TRUE)
df <- df_raw[[1]][["metadata_published"]]
```

The resulting object is class "character" and contains an essentially unintelligible, 80k jumble of .json dictionary elements, like this:

[image]

My question is, how do I extract all the `assetID`s and the `filenames` of the associated .xlsx files and get them into a list or dataframe?

Here's the URL of a sample file (one date of many I need), and what I plan to do with it after I read it in. The alphanumeric phrase after "/files/" in the directory path corresponds to the `assetID`.

```
url <- "https://healthdata.gov/api/views/gqxm-d9w9/files/3bf3ff9c-67d3-47af-aad3-799e21de6e3d?download=true&filename=Community%20Profile%20Report%2020210903.xlsx"

df2 <- read.xlsx(url, sheet=6) %>% select(1,2,6,8,16,76,77) %>% .[-1, ]
colnames(df2) <- c("county","FIPS","state","pop","cases_last7","vaccinated","vacc_prop")
cols.name <- c("FIPS","pop","cases_last7","vaccinated","vacc_prop")
df2[cols.name] <- sapply(df2[cols.name], as.numeric)
df2 <- df2 %>% filter(complete.cases(.)) %>% mutate(cases_last7_100k = cases_last7/pop * 100000) %>%   
        mutate(vacc_prop = vacc_prop*100) %>% filter(state != "PR" & vacc_prop < 100)
```

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be through function `parse_json`  from `jsonlite` package.

Quick and ugly example for the first element:

```r
require(jsonlite)
require(magrittr)
dt <- read_json(path = 'https://healthdata.gov/resource/6hii-ae4f.json')

# as an example, consider only first item from the list 
dt2 <- dt[[1]]$metadata_published %>% parse_json

# str(dt2) to see the parsed object structure.
# we want to loop through the `attachments`
dt2$attachments %>% lapply(.,function(attachment){
  c(filename = attachment$filename, assetId = attachment$assetId)
}) %>% do.call(rbind,.) -> extracted_list

# filter for `xlsx` entries
subset(extracted_list, grepl('*.xlsx', extracted_list[,'filename']))
```

---

For a general case, we could wrap this as a function

```r
'extract_attachments' <- function(x) {
  require(jsonlite)
  require(magrittr)
  x$metadata_published %>% parse_json %>% {
    .$attachments
  } %>%
    lapply(., function(attachment) {
      c(filename = attachment$filename,
        assetId = attachment$assetId)
    }) %>% do.call(rbind, .) %>%
    subset(., grepl('*.xlsx', .[, 'filename']))
}
```

and loop through the whole `json`:

```r
lapply(dt,extract_attachments) %>% do.call(rbind,.)
```

Comment: Thanks!  Perfect.  `parse_json` was the missing link! I clearly need to learn more about "do.call" as well.  Btw, I've never understood why coders use aesthetic terms like "elegant" and "ugly" to describe code.  I didn't think the code was "ugly" at all (not sure why you thought so), but I don't know enough to pass aesthetic judgments on code. Again, many thanks!

Comment: @dbcrow Glad to help! I suppose it depends on the taste. In my case, I meant that I didn't correct a couple of bad habits, like long pipes through ``%>%`` or the ``->`` operator, which were quick and intuitive for me to write, but not the best practice for  "production grade" code. I.e., there are good answers to learn from, and quick answers.

Comment: I prefer long pipes to lots of brackets and parenthesis, in the old base "R" style.  Is it better to break up code over several lines?  I did notice the `->` operator; It struck me as odd, but not necessarily bad. Why would you not want to include that in "production-grade" code?  At all events, this was both a quick answer (again, many thanks!) and one I learnt a great deal from.

Comment: @dbcrow In my experience, long pipes are great, but can be a pain to fix/debug in the future, in case something breaks. It's a lot easier when the code is structured and wrapped into smaller, but well defined functions. There are of course varying opinion on this, but a good place to start is [the tidyverse](https://style.tidyverse.org/index.html) or [google's](https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.html) style guides, and build your own style from there through personal observations.